# appcode can not load underlying module for snapkit

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, appcode

swift project is build and run ok in Xcode also AppCode,
but AppCode IDE report bellow error,I can not fix this .
I found UIProgressView can use progressView.snp but WKWebView can't ,
may be this is problem.

any one can help me ? Now I have to give up appcode .

see:

[image]

#### PodFile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!


target 'fruit-shop-ios' do
  # pod '**', :git => 'http://**.git'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift' #,'4.0.10'
  pod 'SnapKit', '~> 3.2.0'
  # pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way is ignore the error.

> Appcode to format and edit code, Xcode to run.